# in javascript do, what is correct way to get FORM name?

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes, naming

in a form, `form.name` will *usually* return the form's name, but will *not* if the form has an element named "name"

```
var f = document.createElement('form');
f.hasAttribute('name');                   // false
f.name = 'abc';
f.getAttribute('name');                   // "abc"

var i = document.createElement('input');
i.name = 'name';

f.appendChild(i);
f.name;                                   // HTMLInputItem
f.getAttribute('name')                    // "abc"
f.name = 'efg';
f.name;                                   // HTMLInputItem
f.getAttribute('name')                    // "efg"
```

from this exercise, it seems that a FORM's `name` property is really its attribute.

this behavior is drastically different from `value`

```
var i1 = document.createElement('input');
var i2 = document.createElement('input');

// test value
i1.setAttribute('value','value1');
i1.getAttribute('value');                  // value1
i1.value = 'value2';
i1.getAttribute('value');                  // value1

i2.value = 'value1';
i2.hasAttribute('value')                   // false

// test name
i.setAttribute('name','name1');
i.getAttribute('name');                   // name1
i.name = 'name2';
i.getAttribute('name');                   // name2

i2.name = 'name1';
i2.hasAttribute('name')                   // true
```

`value` uses its attribute as a default, whereas `form.name` is a method that first tries elements having `element.name='name'` and then uses the `attribute('name')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is confusion about when and how to access those kind of "special propertys" from a `DOMElement object`. Like `.name`,  `.value`, `.tabIndex`, etc. The direct object access comes from the old days and works just fine in all major browsers. So basically there is nothing wrong by calling

```
form.name
```

But as you mentioned, there might be some trouble if there are named child nodes. The `W3C` recommends to always use the `.setAttribute()` / `.getAttribute()` methods. In this particular instance its probably the best advice to give. On other occasions I'd still go with the direct access since it's just so much less to write and also convinient to me.

Comment: set/getAttribute would be appropriate for `name`, but not for `value`, right?

Comment: the problem with `form.name` is that it is not guaranteed to work - a little feature that took some time to track down.

Comment: If you have `<input name="name">` within the form, then form.name won't return what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to get the form name

> var names[] =
>   document.getElementsByTagName('form').getAttribute('name');

(or)

> var name = document.getElementById('form_id').getAttribute('name');

Comment: That first line isn't JavaScript. Instead you would probably map the array of elements by their "name" attribute, rather than trying to access a `getAttribute` method on the array.